# Mongoose Geospatial Query find all User Spheres which include a given point

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, geospatial

Im trying to find the right way to query the given scenario.

I have a bunch of user with a location latlng and a user defined radius.
And i have a point of interest with an location latlng.
Now i want to find all users their spheres including the latlng of the point of interest.

I provide you how query in the moment but this is obviously wrong.

Schema:

```
    const POISchema = new mongoose.Schema({
                                   poi_uuid: {type: String, required: true},
                                   category_uuid: {type: Number, required: true},
                                   category: {type: String, ref: 'SubCategory'},
                                   activity: {type: String, required: false},
                                   infos: {type: String, required: false},
                                   location: {
                                               coordinates: {type: [Number], index: '2d', required: false, default: []}
                                              }
                                           }, {usePushEach: true}); 


    const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
                                   user_uuid: {type: String, required: true},
                                   helper_radius: {type: Number, required: true},
                                   address: {
                                               coordinates: {type: [Number], index: '2d', required: false, default: []}
                                             }
                                          }, {usePushEach: true});
```

Query:

```
User.find()
                    .and([
                        {
                            latlng: {
                                $near: [parseFloat(obj.coordinates[0]), parseFloat(obj.coordinates[1])],
                                $maxDistance: parseFloat(20 / 111.2)
                            }
                        },
                        {'_id': {'$ne': obj._id}},
                        {'categories': obj.category_uuid}
                    ])
                    .exec(function (err, users) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            return res.send(500, JSON.stringify(err))
                        }
                        return res.send({users: users})
                    })
```

I know that i may have to use $geoWithin or $geoIntersects. But i really don't know how and i read like everything i could find. I even don't find how to declare a schema field with mongoose for a 2d sphere with an defined radius. Maybe somebody can point me in the right direction or has some helpful links.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
var poi; // this is the point of interest for which I want to find the users nearby    
User.aggregate(
    [
        { "$geoNear": {
            "near": poi.location.coordinates,
            "distanceField": "distance"
        }},
        { "$redact": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": { "$lt": [ "$distance", "$helper_radius" ] },
                "then": "$$KEEP",
                "else": "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,results) {
       // read the response
    }
);
```

Comment: The "maxdistance" is defined by the user and can be different for each of them.

Comment: @Sprotte could you please include the Schemas of User and the point of interest?

Comment: Take a look now. You have to use the aggregation framework with the geoNear pipeline. Here are the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/